# Python plotting 2 figures using pylab in realtime

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have the following code for plotting in a single figure

```
import pylab
from pylab import *
xAchse=pylab.arange(0,100,1)
yAchse=pylab.array([0]*100)

fig = pylab.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_title("Realtime Waveform Plot")
ax.set_xlabel("Time")
ax.set_ylabel("Amplitude")
ax.axis([0,100,-1.5,1.5])
line1=ax.plot(xAchse,yAchse,'-')
manager = pylab.get_current_fig_manager()
values=[]
values = [0 for x in range(100)]

Ta=0.01
fa=1.0/Ta
fcos=3.5

Konstant=cos(2*pi*fcos*Ta)
T0=1.0
T1=Konstant

def SinwaveformGenerator(arg):
  global values,T1,Konstant,T0
  #ohmegaCos=arccos(T1)/Ta
  #print "fcos=", ohmegaCos/(2*pi), "Hz"

  Tnext=((Konstant*T1)*2)-T0
  if len(values)%100>70:
    values.append(random()*2-1)
  else:
    values.append(Tnext)
  T0=T1
  T1=Tnext

def RealtimePloter(arg):
  global values
  CurrentXAxis=pylab.arange(len(values)-100,len(values),1)
  line1[0].set_data(CurrentXAxis,pylab.array(values[-100:]))
  ax.axis([CurrentXAxis.min(),CurrentXAxis.max(),-1.5,1.5])
  manager.canvas.draw()
  #manager.show()

timer = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=20)
timer.add_callback(RealtimePloter, ())
timer2 = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=20)
timer2.add_callback(SinwaveformGenerator, ())
timer.start()
timer2.start()

pylab.show()
```

I would like to extend this to plot the same in a 2nd figure. Could someone please give me a tip ?
I tried the following:

```
fig = pylab.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1=ax.plot(xAchse,yAchse,'-') 
fig2 = pylab.figure(2)
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
line2=ax2.plot(xAchse,yAchse,'-')
manager = pylab.get_current_fig_manager()
values=[]
values = [0 for x in range(100)]

Ta=0.01
fa=1.0/Ta
fcos=3.5

Konstant=cos(2*pi*fcos*Ta)
T0=1.0
T1=Konstant

def SinwaveformGenerator(arg):
  global values,T1,Konstant,T0
  #ohmegaCos=arccos(T1)/Ta
  #print "fcos=", ohmegaCos/(2*pi), "Hz"

  Tnext=((Konstant*T1)*2)-T0
  if len(values)%100>70:
    values.append(random()*2-1)
  else:
    values.append(Tnext)
  T0=T1
  T1=Tnext

def RealtimePloter(arg):
  global values
  CurrentXAxis=pylab.arange(len(values)-100,len(values),1)
  line1[0].set_data(CurrentXAxis,pylab.array(values[-100:]))
  ax.axis([CurrentXAxis.min(),CurrentXAxis.max(),-1.5,1.5])
  manager.canvas.draw()
  #manager.show()

timer = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=20)
timer.add_callback(RealtimePloter, ())
timer2 = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=20)
timer2.add_callback(SinwaveformGenerator, ())
timer.start()
timer2.start()

pylab.show()
```

The code generates the second figure but fails to update the first figure. Anytips or ideas would be really helpful Thanks !